# Algebraic geometry papers for beginners

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, soft-question

What are some papers/books suitable for a beginning graduate student interested in algebraic geometry? I have taken commutative algebra and a classical algebraic geometry class, but I have no other experience relevant to algebraic geometry.

I've heard of Harris, but I'm also looking for other references (e.g. papers if possible).

Comment: There are two MO threads ([here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/1291/a-learning-roadmap-for-algebraic-geometry) and [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/35288/undergraduate-roadmap-to-algebraic-geometry)) which may provide some guidance on where to look next.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not familiar with etiquette regarding these types of "big list" questions, but here is a personal recommendation.

I highly recommend János Kollár's ["The structure of algebraic threefolds: an introduction to Mori's program"](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1987-17-02/S0273-0979-1987-15548-0/). The paper requires a bit more sophistication on the topological and complex analytic side of algebraic geometry, but this is why it was so amazing when I read it: it brought many areas of math together in a coherent way that helped my intuition greatly. The paper starts with a general overview of what algebraic geometry is about, and by the end you have a pretty good idea of how the minimal model program works in dimension 3.

Prof. Kollár also wrote another similar article giving a more modern account of open conjectures and problems in this area. It's "The structure of algebraic varieties" and you can find it on p. 395 of the [first volume of ICM proceedings from last year](http://www.icm2014.org/download/Proceedings_Volume_I.pdf).

Comment: Here's [Kollar's copy on the arXiv](http://arxiv.org/abs/1407.7478). These are awesome suggestions -- I think if you're interested in the Mori program then everything he's written is solid gold. What can be scary is that he makes clear the need to bring in the other viewpoints and coming from the algebraic purity of Hartshorne that's a bit of a shock.